# JQuery for regresa muchos resultados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una pequeña practica, cuatro cajas y al presionar la que contiene el id elemento, mostrar un mensaje, funciona pero se imprime el alert mas de 100 veces.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var elemento = $(".elemento");

$(".elemento").click(function(){
    for (const llave in elemento) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "elemento"){
            alert("si");
        }   
    }


})


})
```

Comment: es un for in no un foreach

Comment: como estás iniciando, esto te ayudará mucho: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si solo quieres mostrar un alert al presionar el elemento con id 'elemento' lo mejor es:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#elemento").click(function(){   
    alert("si");
  })
})
```

Si forzosamente en tu práctica debes iterar el arreglo, usa la función [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) de jQuery, de esa manera estarás iterando el arreglo con la clase '.elemento' siguiendo los estándares de jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo entender de tu código, no necesitas un bucle. El keyword `this` es el elemento que hayas cliqueado

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".elemento").click(function(){   
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "elemento"){
            alert("si");
        }   

  })
})
```